# Manual implementation of np.std(x, axis = 0)

Tags: python, numpy, std

I am trying to manually implement the np.std() function with the arguments being an array and axis = 0. The code I came up with does not seem to work tho.

```
test_array = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
s_test = np.sum((test_array - np.mean(test_array, axis = 0))**2, axis = 0)
s_div = s_test/test_array.size
sqrt = np.sqrt(s_div)
```

The formular I am using is sqrt(sum(x-mean)^2)/amount of element) which should according to `np.std(test_array, axis = 0)` output `array([1.5, 1.5, 1.5])` but it actually outputs `array([0.8660254, 0.8660254, 0.8660254])`.

Comment: `test_array.size` is the total number of elements in `test_array`. You probably meant to use the number of rows in `test_array`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem.